# Time-out when deploying a smart contract

Tags: contract-deployment, ethers.js, contract-upgrading

I have two Node.js/ether projects that use the same code and dependencies to deploy an upgradeable smart contract written in Solidity.

They use these lines:

```
const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, bytecode, wallet)
const hardhat = require("hardhat")
contract = await hardhat.upgrades.deployProxy(
  contractFactory,
  [tokenAddress],
  {
    initializer: "initialize"
  }
)
const contractDeployed = await contract.deployed()
```

and these dependencies:

```
  "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "2.2.3",
  "@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades": "1.20.0",
  "hardhat": "2.22.1",
```

In one project, everything works fine, whereas the other always runs into a time-out ("Timed out waiting for implementation contract deployment to address ...").

What can cause this?
How can I analyze what gets sent to Infura.io? Wireshark does not even find the requests.